# Android getExternalStorageDirectory doesn't return any file

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android programming.
I'm trying to get the path to files on my nexus device by using `getExternalStorageDirectory()`
But it returns no file at all

Code:

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"");
path.mkdirs();
if (path.exists()) {
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                File sel = new File(dir, filename);
                // Filters based on whether the file is hidden or not
                return (sel.isFile() || sel.isDirectory())
                    && !sel.isHidden();

            }
        };
String[] fList = path.list(filter);
// flist return null
}
```

Comment: which file you're trying to get ?

Comment: I want to get folders like download or images what ever I try it return null I want to explore all file and directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in your case you can fetch all data by doing following code:

```
ArrayList<String> filesList = new ArrayList<String>();   
String sd_card = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
file = new File( sd_card ) ;       
File list[] = file.listFiles();
for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++) {
    filesList.add( list[i].getName() );
}
```

Now `filesList` will have list of all files , you can use it as per your need.

Please don't forget to add permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: It return path expiation path dose not exis. Is their away to get internal storeg since nexus doesn't have SD card

Comment: I add the permission put the path is wrong when I use your code file path return /storeg/sdcard/external_SD. No Such directory.

Comment: Still.         file.listfiles return null like if the directory is empty??

Comment: debug string sd_card like Log.d("PATH", sd_card ); and check your log what it returns, and paste it here.

Comment: then there must not be any file in your directory. check the device you're testing on.

Comment: I'm testing on nexus 4 device. Their is download file and gallery files. Thank you for been patient with me.

Comment: please note that `getExternalStorageDirectory` returns already a `File`. There is no need of use `new File()`

Answer (score 2):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>"` to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I add this permission still no luck